# What is the pros and cons of centralizing applications logs?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am looking to understand the pros and cons of centralizing all applications logs into separate files with AOP (*e.g.* with AspectJ).

[Logging is know for being a cross-cutting concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern). However, I have never met anyone that centralized all logs into a single or bunch of files. Therefore, I'm left wondering why.

What would be some of the pros and cons of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am looking to understand the pros and cons of centralizing all
> applications logs into separate files with AOP (e.g. with AspectJ).

I will be using the terms AOP and AspectJ interchangeably. Notwithstanding, AOP is the paradigm and AspectJ implements it, just like OOP and Java.

The benefits of centralizing cross-cutting concerns (CCC) into their own modules (*e.g.,* aspect) using [AOP](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Egregor/papers/kiczales-ECOOP1997-AOP.pdf) are similar to those of modularization concerns with `OOP`. Those benefits are described in the literature in papers and books such as:

- [Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Egregor/papers/kiczales-ECOOP1997-AOP.pdf)
- [Towards a Common Reference Architecture for Aspect-Oriented Modeling](https://publik.tuwien.ac.at/files/pub-inf_3843.pdf)
- [Impact of aspect-oriented programming on software development efficiency and design quality: an empirical study.](https://digital-library.theiet.org/content/journals/10.1049/iet-sen_20060071)
- [AspectJ in Action: Enterprise AOP with Spring](https://www.developerfusion.com/book/17055/aspectj-in-action-enterprise-aop-with-spring/)

and many others. One can summarize some of those benefits as follows:

- **reduces code duplication;** Instead of having a functionality (*e.g.,* logging) duplicated in several different places, one has it in a single aspect. That functionality can then be applied to those several places using the concept of *pointcut*;
- **reduces the coupling** between domain-related and crosscutting-related concerns (*i.e.,* separation of concerns); For instance, removing the logging from the domain code follows the [single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle);
- **the enhancing of code reusability;** Because of the aforementioned separation of concerns, one (for instance) increases the reusability of the modules encapsulating the based code and the modules encapsulating the logging;
- dealing with code [tangling and scattering issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern); as illustrated in the image below

[image]

Instead of having logging 1 and 2 **tangled** directly with the domain-code, duplicated and **scattered** across separate modules (*i.e.,* `Class A` and `Class B`), we have those logging-related functionality encapsulated into one aspect.

There are in the literature some papers about the benefit of AOP regarding the modularization of cross-cutting concerns such as logging namely:

> S. Canditt and M. Gunter. Aspect oriented logging in a real-world
> system. In First AOSD Workshop on Aspects, Components, and Patterns
> for Infrastructure Software (AOSD-2002), March 2002.

The downsides of AOP that one can read in the literature are [those typical of a learning/integrating a new technology](https://www.developerfusion.com/book/17055/aspectj-in-action-enterprise-aop-with-spring/), namely:

> - Hiring skilled programmers
> - Following an adoption path to ensure that you don’t risk the project by overextending yourself
> - Modifying the build and other development processes
> - Dealing with the availability of tools

Other downsides reported by papers such as:

- [An exploratory study of the effect of aspect-oriented programming on maintainability](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11219-007-9022-7)
- [Using aspect-orientation in industrial projects: appreciated or damned?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221014749_Using_aspect-orientation_in_industrial_projects_appreciated_or_damned)
- [Using and reusing aspects in aspectj.](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.21.8517&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [A Case Study Implementing Features Using AspectJ](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/ftp/predator/SPLC07.pdf) (this one is particularly good a show-casing some of issues with using AOP

can be summarize to:

- having to **learn** a new paradigm;
- lack of **tool support**;
- the **performance** of the weaving;
- **making it harder to reason about the code**, since the CCC related code was moved elsewhere. The same argument can be applied to subclassing or the use of the decorated pattern for instance. However, IDEs mitigates those problems, in the case of `AspectJ` by showing the joinpoints that are being intercepted. Another solution is for instance to use annotations and intercept those annotations:

  @Logging
  public void some_method(){...}

When the programmer looks at the annotation immediately knows that that method is being intercepted by a pointcut. The downside of this approach is that you *kind* mixing again the CCCs with the domain code, albeit just in a form of an annotation.

On the other hand one can argue that since the domain-related concerns and CCCs are now encapsulated in different modules it is easier to reason about them in isolation.

- [**Pointcut fragility**](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228598592_PCDiff_Attacking_the_fragile_pointcut_problem); This problem is similar to the [fragile base class problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class). From [source](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5431730) one can read:

> changes to the base-code can lead to join points incorrectly falling
> in or out of the scope of pointcuts.

For instance, adding new methods, or changing their signature might cause pointcuts to intercept them or stop intercepting them. There are techniques to mitigate such problems. However, in my option the solution is tooling. When one renames a method in Java one expects the IDE to safely apply those changes.

- **the granularity of the joinpoint module**. With AspectJ (even worse with Spring AOP) it might be difficult to get local context necessary for the logging, for instance local variables, which might force you to refactor your code so that you can expose the desired *joinpoints* -- [known in requirements engineering as scaffolding](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-22031-9_2). On the other side, refactoring your code might actually improve it. From: ["21. Why can't AspectJ pick out local variables (or array elements or ...)?"](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/faq.php#q:newjoinpoints) one can read:

> Users have sometimes wanted AspectJ to pick out many more join points,
> including method-local field access, array-element access, loop iteration, method parameter evaluation
>
> Most of these have turned out not to make sense, for a variety of
> reasons: it is not a commonly-understood unit for Java programmers
>
> - there are very few use-cases for advice on the join point
> - a seemingly-insignificant change to the underlying program causes a
>   change in the join point
> - pointcuts can't really distinguish the join point in question
> - the join point would differ too much for different implementations of
>   AspectJ, or would only be implementable in one way
>
> **We prefer to be very conservative in the join point model for the
> language, so a new join point would have to be useful, sensible, and
> implementable. The most promising of the new join points proposed are
> for exception throws clauses and for synchronized blocks.**

You need to evaluate if in your context it pay-off adding an extra layer (*i.e.,* *transversal modularization*) into your code base; and also evaluate against alternative approaches such as code-generators, frameworks or design patterns.

In the case of the logging some of the aforementioned issues are not as *problematic* because if things go wrong... well you *just* lose or add some logging.

**Opinion base part**

**Logging is know for being a cross-cutting concern. However, I have never met anyone that centralized all logs into a single or bunch of files. Therefore, I'm left wondering why.**

Is *separation of concerns* a bad practice?! (unless you take it to the extreme no). I would definitely say that is not a bad practice, is it worth?! well that is more complex and context depended.

I personally *hate* to see a *beautiful* snippet of code mixed with logging functionality. IMO given that software has to deal with so many other variables than just the code per *si*, such as tight deadlines, not having logging mixed with base code seems to not have a higher priority.

Comment: Fantastic answer, exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much for the links too

Comment: Thanks for collecting these papers in an overview, very helpful. I am of course a strong AOP (especially AspectJ) proponent and do not agree with some of the findings in those mostly old papers (one even mentions AspectJ not having reached 1.0 status). Also the learning curve and "hard to read" arguments do not really convince me. It seems that the scientists who conducted those studies were not very experienced in using AspectJ, i.e. we have a situation in which relative beginners try to do something advanced. I might be wrong here, but it has that kind of smell to me.

Comment: The few people around the globe with enough AOP experience who could serve as coaches on the job are IMO under-utilised. This is a waste because AOP is enterprise-ready, has a big potential and can help solve many real world design, programming and maintenance problems if not over-used or even abused for bad hacks covering up bad OOP design. I for example, being the person with the highest reputation by far here on SO regarding AOP and AspectJ, rarely receive commercial inquiries for coaching or training other than from my existing clients.

Comment: It seems like people just use free resources like StackOverflow and product documentation as learning tools, which probably is not enough to quickly get from an experimental to an operational phase in AOP usage. They play by themselves, of course it is hard (like every new tool or paradigm is hard to wrap your head around at first), then they give up and decide it is not worth the effort. Don't get me wrong, I am not so much ***com***plaining but rather ***ex***plaining why I think AOP is underrated and never really took off beyond the confines of "AOP lite" in Spring AOP, which is a shame.

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks for your comments, when I have the time I will add a bit more references , and actually structure the answer a bit better. Yes, I am also a fan of AOP and AspectJ in particular. In the past I have done quite some work with it. Most of the papers in AOP are rather old because they where created during the technology-hype. Long term really research in the topic is rare... so it is naturally that one reads those papers and wonders. Nonetheless, IMO the best arguments "against" AOP comes from the papers of Don Batory and Sven Apel, but they also a bit "bias" towards FOP.

Comment: I recommend the reading of Sven Apel PhD thesis "The role of features and aspects in software development: similarities, differences, and synergetic potential."  there in the end Sven actually also promotes the use AOP but as a complement to FOP, rather than replacement. Yes, I also agree that "people" tend to misuse AOP; IMO AOP needs disciple so that you avoid some of its pitfalls such as misusing of the wildcards and catching too much, using around almost as a "goto" , and so on.

Comment: One of the arguments use for the complexity is that since you remove the CCC into an aspect now it gets more difficult to reason about the code because the CCC are not explicitly there which it also sound to me like a bit like a straw argument. A more valid argument IMO is the fact if you put all the same CCC into a single aspect (i.e., logging) then the aspect becomes too big, but that can be ameliorated by create multiple aspects but then you get a bit of code scattering which was what you were trying to avoid in the beginning, but one case see it as a bit of a trade-off.

Comment: Another complain is that AspectJ joinpoint model is not fine grain enough, for example it should allow catching local variables. I personally also disagree because if it were more fine grain then it would be even harder to control. Spring AOP at least made it more mainstream I would say, but at the end of the day the success of a technology is measured by "how much" it is used in production. And I might be wrong since I have not touch AspectJ for a while but I would say that the tooling was far from great and that the weaving times were a bit too slow. But again I mostly used it with eclipse.